# Getting duplicate error in mongoose, after removing unique : true from last

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data from an API and print it. But it is constantly giving

**MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection** error

Below is the index.js and the schema code

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const ejs = require("ejs")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));



const app = express()
const port = 3002

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.json())

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Quadb-tech', () => {
        console.log("Connected to database successfully")
    });
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    buy: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    sell: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    volume: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {

    url = "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/tickers"

    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    let mydata = Object.entries(data).slice(0, 10).map(e => e[1]);

    mydata.map((data) => {
        const data1 = new User({

            name: data.name,
            last: data.last,
            sell: data.sell,
            buy: data.buy,
            volume: data.volume

        })
        data1.save()
    })
    const result = await User.find({})
    res.render("landing", { mydata: result })

    // res.render("first")

});

// app.get("/landing", async (req, res) => {
//     const result = await User.find({})
//     console.log(result);
//     res.render("landing", { mydata: result })

// })



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

an below is the error which is getting rendered every time:

Connected to database successfully
C:\Quadb-tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert.js:53
return callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(res.writeErrors[0]));
^

```
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: Quadb-tech.users index: last_1 dup key: { last: "124.0" }
    at C:\Quadb-tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert.js:53:33
    at C:\Quadb-tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:273:25
    at handleOperationResult (C:\Quadb-tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:327:20)
    at Connection.onMessage (C:\Quadb-tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:215:9)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\Quadb-tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:63:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Quadb-tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Quadb-tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10) {
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { last: 1 },
  keyValue: { last: '124.0' },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have searched on the net for the error, and most suggested removing the unique: true and after doing that also, it is showing the error. The page is rendered for a time but on refreshing, it shows this error.

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the collection and create it try again

Comment: Okay thanks, looking into it!!